# Открытие терминала при запуске программы

Tags: c++, qtcreator, виджет

Совсем недавно начал работать с qt creator. Сделал программу: виджет - расширения .app с десятком кнопок, при нажатии на каждую запускается отдельная программа, которая требует ввода в терминале, да и отображение результатов идет в терминале.
Когда запускаешь проект непосредственно в Qt - автоматически открывается терминал и там все отображается(соответствующая галка в настройках стоит). Однако когда открываешь .app файл с рабочего стола - виджет открывается, но при нажатии кнопок в нем - терминал с исполняемой программой не появляется. Как решить данную проблему?
Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Решить данную проблему просто - нужно запускать ваши "внешние" программы в терминале :-) с определенными ключами (аргументами, если точнее). Вот тут обсуждение, как [запустить внешний процесс](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622864/start-a-process-using-qprocess). Для Windows терминалом послужит `cmd.exe`. Для *nix - выбираете, что нужно. Допустим `xterm`.

При запуске и `cmd.exe`, и `xterm` - есть ключи, которые позволят терминалу запуститься, и сразу выполнить указанную программу. Для этого нужно смотреть документацию - там все подробно описано.

Comment: Работаю в MacOS
Пробовал запускать непосредственно в терминале, просто через командную строку - то же самое происходит
Не очень понял, какие именно аргументы здесь могут пригодиться.
Прошу прощения, было бы здорово, если бы подробнее смогли объяснить саму механику(почему необходимо дополнительно qprocess запускать, как указано в ссылке, например). 
Попробую сделать, как в указанной ссылке.